# How to trigger transition when data is loaded in component in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

i'm currently working on a project with vue.js and vue-router. I got a vue in which I display some news, and I got thoses news from an API (it's kind of a blog).

I'm currently loading thoses news inside the `router.data` to set the data for the component, as said [here](http://router.vuejs.org/en/pipeline/data.html). It's working great, no problems.

But my problem is that I want to animate the apparition of the news when I go to this view. I've tried using the `ready` property from the component, but it's called before the `router.data` has finished getting the news, which result in errors in animation, because there aren't any elements.

How can i trigger the animations once the news I fetch are fully rendered inside the DOM ?

Here is the code of my component:

```
export default {
  name: 'News',
  data: function () {
    return {
      news: []
    }
  },
  route: {
    data: function (transition) {
      console.log('data hook')
      return api
      .getPostsByLimit(4, 1)
      .then(function (posts) {
        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
          var post = posts[i]
          post.formatedDate = moment(post.date).format("D MMM. YYYY")
          post.dateTime = moment(post.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
          if(post.news_artist_related) {
            post.news_artist_related = JSON.parse(post.news_artist_related)
            post.news_artist_related.type = slugify(post.news_artist_related.type)
            post.news_artist_related.slug = slugify(post.news_artist_related.slug)
          }
        }
        return posts
      })
      .then(news => ({news}))
    }
  },
  ready: function () {
    console.log('Ready hook')
    animateNewsApparition()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://router.vuejs.org/en/pipeline/data.html):

> When resolved, the component will also emit a 'route-data-loaded' event.

So:

```
events: {
  'route-data-loaded': function() {
    animateNewsApparition()
  }
}
```